# Exchange rejecting php mail from same domain

Tags: php, email, exchange-server

I have an IIS server running PHP on an Apache Module. I am running a domain on it, and this domain has a seperate setup for email which uses an exchange server. When I try to send email from the website using php mail() the exchange server rejects it. I.e. the header from line is sender@this-domain.com and it is sending to receiver@this-domain.com, both are email addresses set up in the exchange, even though the sender has no direct relationship with exchange.

The emails are not getting through. We tried using a Yahoo adress in the from line but nothing. Has anyone ever come across a problem like this.

Comment: Check the IIS SMTP log, it'd most likely have more details why mail is getting rejected.

Comment: What's the return-path of the email? Is it a valid email adress (or at least a valid domain)?

Comment: @marc-b The reply is: 550 5.1.1 <user@samedomain.co.uk>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table @capsule yes

Answer (score 0):

You have to either configure the exchange server to accept relay requests based on the origin ip or some transparent authorization mechanism (don't know much about IIS and Exchange and integrated windows authentication, but the good people over at http://serverfault.com do. ). Or use some mailing library that can handle smpt authentication like e.g. http://swiftmailer.org

Answer (score 0):

I once ran into a problem like this which involved the Exchange server not wanting to accept anonymous connections or that it would only accept mail from certain SMTP servers. Have you checked the configuration on your Exchange server to eliminate those possibilities?

Comment: @Phillip the server is functioning fine, it is even receiving email using the exact same php code block, just not from the same domain that the exchange server is on, seems like it is some sort of clash